# Pass values from one form to other in OpenERP-7

Tags: python, forms, odoo

I have a button in my form. And through that button I am calling another form. I am trying to pass values of form'A' to be set on the field of form'B'. I am using return to open the form. I tried with context.update to set the field values of form'B'. But the values did not pass. Nor I am having any error. My python code is as below:

```
def creates(self,cr,uid,ids,context):
     for id in ids:
         deg_obj=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
         my_id=int(deg_obj.my_products)
     prr= int(deg_obj.categg_temp)
     pch= int(deg_obj.categ_temps)
     cch= int(deg_obj.categ_temp2)
     return{
              'view_type': 'form',
              'view_mode': 'form',
              'res_model': 'product.product',
              'context': context.update({'pr': prr}),
              'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
              'nodestroy':False,
              'target': 'inline',
              }
```

I really need help on this. Because I have learnt that for this, we have to use context.update, but I dont where I am wrong here. PLz guide me on this.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

You have a form 'A' which has field 'Afield_name' and you want to load that value to form 'B' to the field 'Bfield_name'. Everything you are doing is correct except the context. Key in the context should be 'default_'+your_field_name

```
def creates(self,cr,uid,ids,context):
     for id in ids:
         deg_obj=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
         my_id=int(deg_obj.my_products)
         prr= int(deg_obj.Afield_name)

     return{
              'view_type': 'form',
              'view_mode': 'form',
              'res_model': 'product.product',
              'context': context.update({'default_Bfield_name': prr}),
              'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
              'nodestroy':False,
              'target': 'current',
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the context before assigning it in return

```
def creates(self,cr,uid,ids,context):
 for id in ids:
     deg_obj=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
     my_id=int(deg_obj.my_products)
 prr= int(deg_obj.categg_temp)
 pch= int(deg_obj.categ_temps)
 cch= int(deg_obj.categ_temp2)
 context.update({'default_pr': prr})
 return{
          'view_type': 'form',
          'view_mode': 'form',
          'res_model': 'product.product',
          'context': context,
          'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
          'nodestroy':False,
          'target': 'inline',
          }
```

Comment: which method are you using to get the context of form A, I mean are you using create, write, or any other method to fetch context ?

Comment: no I am not using any specific method. All I am doing is return form with those values.

Comment: But where are you checking on form B for context values ?

Comment: as you see in my code, when I print the values of 'prr',pch,cch it gives me the correct values. But these values are not passing to the other form. When I load the other form, the field should have these values because I have used context.update.

Comment: Please see the answer of OmaL which uses the good way : put 'default_your_field_name' as key in context.